# Why can't I set the order in which Unit Tests will be executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm learning about Testing reading the Rails doc, which states you can sort the order in which the tests are executed (random by default) by modifying either the application.rb or the environment files and adding:

```
config.active_support.test_order = :sorted
```

The environment files take precedence over those in config/application.rb. I've tried both but I can't make it work either way.

I have the exact same 3 tests in my model, for which I changed the names to 1, 2 and 3 and they are executed randomly each time.

```
  test "1" do
    article = Article.new
    assert_not article.save, "Saved the article without a title"
  end

  test "2" do
    article = Article.new
    assert_not article.save, "Saved the article without a title"
  end

  test "3" do
    article = Article.new
    assert_not article.save, "Saved the article without a title"
  end
```

returns 1,3,2 (test order is random every time I run rails test)

```
F

Failure:
ArticleTest#test_1 [/home/elianvm/code/1990eam/blog_for_testing_training/test/models/article_test.rb:18]:
Saved the article without a title


rails test test/models/article_test.rb:16

F

Failure:
ArticleTest#test_3 [/home/elianvm/code/1990eam/blog_for_testing_training/test/models/article_test.rb:28]:
Saved the article without a title


rails test test/models/article_test.rb:26

F

Failure:
ArticleTest#test_2 [/home/elianvm/code/1990eam/blog_for_testing_training/test/models/article_test.rb:23]:
Saved the article without a title


rails test test/models/article_test.rb:21
```

Comment: As a note, order-dependent tests are considered broken, which is why the default is random. That shakes out order-dependency problems really quick.

Comment: Are you sure that setting is correctly applied? It's worth checking in the tests that it is. The config can be inspected after the fact.

Comment: Do you have a conflicting config somewhere else, e.g. `config/environments/test.rb`, that might be taking precedence? Try searching your code base for any conflict. I don't see anything wrong, given the limited information you've supplied, which would cause test results to still run in a random order.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? If I create a new rails project and set the test order to `:sorted`, then it does work for me.

Comment: I basically used the Rails Get Started guide (official doc) which the Testing doc references to. It's a basic blog App with an Article and Commenter models. I created the models and controllers via the command line so pretty much everything is default.

I have nothing else that references the testing order in either of the files I described and I don't know where else to look.

Comment: I can reproduce this following the [Rails testing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html). I can also confirm test_order is set by adding a `p test_order` within ArticleTest.

Comment: What do you mean with "p test_order"? @Schwern

Comment: @1990eam I mean to print [the test order](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html#method-c-test_order) within the test to verify the configuration option is being set. Put it just after `class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase`. As you change `config.active_support.test_order `, the `test_order` within the test should also change. This verifies that the test order is being set, and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. It prints sorted indeed.